# Django tutorial, Page not found <int:question_id>

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

When I going at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/' I receive 'Page not found' error but I definitely have this question_id, I can see this question_id in shell, it doesn't matter what ID I have write I always receive the same issue.

[Image from my web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOc8k.png)

Comment: Please add the output of your `runserver` command as well. Does it receive the `GET` request?

Comment: Not Found: /polls/1/
[23/Mar/2023 16:31:35] "GET /polls/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2853

Answer (score 0):

I have find answer
I just need to write slash before in my

```
path('/<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

it's look like some sort of mistake in Django documentation.
Many thanks for everyone attention!

Answer (score 0):

OK. Maybe is not your django app connected to site?

*your_site/your_site/urls.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```